# String[]tempString=multipleValues.split("-"); but int the format for creating an array String[]array=new String[10];?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, string

```
public void pushMany(String multipleValues){
String[]tempString=multipleValues.split("-");
for(int i=0;i<tempString.length;i++){
    push(tempString [i]);   
    }
}
```

I am used to creating arrays using String[]array=new String[10]; or creating multidimensional arrays such as String[]array={"car","truck"};
Therefore, I am not sure what is going on with this??? Is it still assigned an array?

Comment: How is `String[] array = {"car","truck"};` multidimensional?

Answer (score 0):

`String.split("-")` function returns an array of Strings separated by "-". Therefore yes it is assigned an array!

Refer to [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_split.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) is quite clear:

> [Returns] the array of strings computed by splitting this string around matches of the given regular expression

so yes, the value assigned to `tempString` is a `String[]`.

Answer (score -1):

The String class has a method split

```
public String[] split(String regex)
```

[Quoting the java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)):

> Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.
>
> This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with
>   the given expression and a limit argument of zero.
>
> Trailing empty
>   strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

so when you do `split("-")` you are searching conincidences in the string that matches the "-" and the result is an array